How to filter with docker system prune to exclude only specific images according to the tag number?
I have several services, each service has its own image, each new image is created with a tag number.
CONTAINER ID                    IMAGE                        CREATED            NAMES
d5362c516ceb   19.185.88.72:5000/service1_backend_dev:12     2 days ago     dev_service1_backend
34553e44d748   19.185.88.72:5000/img_service2_dev:9          3 days ago     dev_service2_backend
bd716a0edf45   19.185.88.72:5000/img_service3_dev:10         4 days ago     dev_service3_backend
844d028da74e   19.185.88.72:5000/service1_frontend_dev:9     10 days ago    dev_service1_frontend
c2039ba8aac0   19.185.88.72:5000/img_service4_dev:3          12 days ago    dev_service4_backend
c7908aa8b6ca   19.185.88.72:5000/service5_frontend_dev:3     13 days ago    dev_service5_frontend
395df52b0847   19.185.88.72:5000/cron_service6_dev:2         3 weeks ago    dev_service6_backend
3562fcba7dfc   19.185.88.72:5000/service7_backend_dev:2      3 weeks ago    dev_service7_backend
02e9bfafacc4   19.185.88.72:5000/service8_frontend_dev:5     3 weeks ago    dev_service8_frontend
f0edae181190   19.185.88.72:5000/service5_backend_dev:2      3 weeks ago    dev_service5_backend
ba730b74f7f6   19.185.88.72:5000/service8_backend_dev:3      3 weeks ago    dev_service8_backend
a2d6561e5827   19.185.88.72:5000/extracao_service9_dev:1     3 weeks ago    dev_service9_backend
02952dd3f6ec   19.185.88.72:5000/service7_frontend_dev:1     3 weeks ago    dev_service7_frontend

I want to know if it is possible to use docker system prune ignoring the 2 most recent images of each service and deleting all the other ones.
Something like if the last is "image:6" then I use system prune and delete the images with tag : 3,2,1 for that service and preserve the images with the tags 4 and 5.
I tried filtering by time like this docker system prune -a --filter "until=$((($(date +%s) - (86400 * 7))))" but some services are not updated too often and all images are deleted. So a possible solution is to use the tag numbers of each service.

Plain Docker on its own doesn't have this capability directly (nor do most other tools – could you do this on similarly-named filer with ls and rm?).  Does the awk script in Print first N rows per group -> Remove all docker images except newest N for each image name work for you?
